# Why did Jesus - not baptize?. John 4:2

Tags: john, jesus, baptism

John 4:2 (NASB)

> 2 (although Jesus Himself was not baptizing, but His disciples were),

Answer (score 1):

"Why didn't Jesus baptize with water" would be a better question.  The reason I clarify this is because there are about 14 things a person could be baptized in, in the new testament.  See these few verses:

> 1 Cor. 10:2 and all were baptized into Moses in the cloud and in the
>   sea;
>
> Acts 11:16 And I remembered the word of the Lord, how He used to say,
>   ‘John baptized with water, but you will be baptized with the Holy
>   Spirit.’

All of this to say it is a mistake to assume water baptism each time we see the word in the New Testament.  Secondly, these questions must be asked, "What was the purpose of Jesus living, dying, and resurrecting?" and what is the purpose of being baptized in water?

Jesus' mission was to give His life as a ransom for the sins of humanity.  This is applied to one's account via faith and not water baptism.  Baptism in water was a way to publicly identity oneself with Jesus.  It's more akin to wearing a wedding ring.  Wearing a wedding ring does not make one married, it simply shows the world you belong to your spouse.  Water baptism doesn't make one redeemed, it simply shows the world you have believed in Jesus.  It's a way to identify with a message or a person.

When Jesus was baptized He was basically identifying with John's message.

> 2 “Repent, for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.” 11 “As for me, I
>   baptize you with water for repentance, but He who is coming after me
>   is mightier than I, and I am not fit to remove His sandals; He will
>   baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire. 12 His winnowing fork is in
>   His hand, and He will thoroughly clear His threshing floor; and He
>   will gather His wheat into the barn, but He will burn up the chaff
>   with unquenchable fire.”

Answer (score 0):

And I myself did not know him, but the one who sent me to baptize with water told me, ‘The man on whom you see the Spirit come down and remain is the one who will baptize with the Holy Spirit.’ John 1:33 New International Version (NIV)

While John baptized with water for repentance, this would baptize with the Holy Spirit and with fire.

Let us observe,

**I myself did not know him**, but the reason I came baptizing with water was that he might be revealed to Israel.” John 1:31 New International Version (NIV)

What do you mean you didn’t know him?

Jesus and John the Baptist were cousins, and closely related by the circumstances of their birth; Jesus visited Jerusalem every year. Luke 2:41-43

And I myself did not know him, but the one who sent me to baptize with water told me, ‘The man on whom you see the Spirit come down and remain is the one who will baptize with the Holy Spirit.’ I have seen and I testify that **this is God’s Chosen One**.” John 1:33-34 New International Version (NIV)

John the Baptist did not know who the son of God was, but knew Jesus.